# Why dose my peelesd valve seat only last a few days?

Tags: leaking

I dont know the model of the faucet the repair kit comes with two seals and two small Springs . My water temperature is 135 degrees at the faucet.

Comment: Peelees?  We are going to need much more info.

Comment: What's a peelesd, peeless valve?  How about some pictures of the insides of the base.

Comment: Tom please take time to proof read your words, correct spelling,  and be more descriptive in telling us what you have done and what faucet you have.  It very difficult to understand you.

Answer (score 1):

If the plate that the o-rings slide on is scarred that may be cutting the rings up. Hard to guess at anything other than that with the info provided.